# DataTables - count each type of option

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a simple datatables setup. There are 1000 rows. One column can only have 4 different values.

I need to find out how many of each type there are. I've looked at https://datatables.net/reference/api/count() but it doesn't seem to do what I need.

Any advice? Someone mentioned https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/blob/master/features/alphabetSearch/dataTables.alphabetSearch.js#L61 but I wouldn't know where to begin

Thanks

Comment: How are you pulling your information you're working with? Why can't you do this then rather than when you are dealing with Front-End?

Comment: It comes from a pre-defined report which I can't control

Comment: What languages are you dealing with? You plan on doing this with jQuery/js?

Comment: Yes - as the keywords suggest, I'll be looking at jQuery/DataTables

Comment: have you tried to do `var binnedData = bin(data);` Then output in DOM or console to see what that makes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a fairly easy task if it is just about counting the number of certain values for a specific column. You can even implement it as a plug-in :

```js
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register('countValue()', function(index, value) {
   var count = 0;
   var data = this.data();
   for (var d in data) {
     if (data[d][index] == value) count++
   }
   return count;
});
```

Now you can do

```js
console.log('Developer', table.countValue(2, 'Developer'));
console.log('Regional Marketing', table.countValue(2, 'Regional Marketing'));
console.log('Software Engineer', table.countValue(2, 'Software Engineer'));
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hmwLw2yw/**

If you are using a JSON source, it could be an AJAX request, refer to the item attribute name instead of the array index :

```js
console.log('Developer', table.countValue('position', 'Developer'));
console.log('Regional Marketing', table.countValue('position', 'Regional Marketing'));
console.log('Software Engineer', table.countValue('position', 'Software Engineer'));
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ytw647ak/**